# Как сделать Embed в 2 линии и в 2 столбца? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мне нужно сделать что бы Embed располагался так что бы 2 блока было в первом ряду и 2 блока во-втором ряду, но у меня получается только в первом ряду 2 блока во-втором 1 блок и еще третий ряд получается с 1 блоком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно сделать что бы Монеты и Очки были на 1 линии, как это можно сделать?

```
@client.command()
async def stat(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Статистика', color=discord.Colour.blue())
    emb.add_field(name='Name', value=f'{ctx.message.author}', inline=True)
    emb.add_field(name='Ранг', value='На калибровке', inline=True)
    emb.add_field(name='Монеты', value='0', inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Очки', value='0', inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def stat(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Статистика', color=discord.Colour.blue())
    emb.add_field(name='Name', value=f'{ctx.message.author}', inline=True)
    emb.add_field(name='Ранг', value='На калибровке', inline=True)
    emb.add_field(name='Монеты', value='0', inline=True)
    emb.add_field(name='Очки', value='0', inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: У вас в первой линии 3 столбца, а во второй 1 столбец, проверяйте пожалуйста код который вы написали